# How to use the Android GreenMatter lib to change ColorAccent, ColorPrimary in Code?

Tags: android, overriding

Hi i want to use the GreenMatter (https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter) lib to change ColorAccent, ColorPrimary and others by code (Programmatically override the colors at runtime).

I have setup the lib in my Android Project with https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter/wiki/Basic-GreenMatter-setup. But by analyzing the Greenmatter code i can't find out how i could use for example a integer (color) to change
ColorAccent or ColorPirmary in my Android Project.

Comment: `Color.parseColor("#636161")` OR `Resources res = getResources();
int color = res.getColor(R.color.opaque_red);` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the steps in the [setup guide](https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter/wiki/Basic-GreenMatter-setup), you should have an `Activity` that extends `MatActivity`. In your `Activity` you can change the default colors of your theme by overriding `overridePalette()` and setting the colors as you'd like in the `MatPalette` object parameter and returning it.

```
public class MyActivity extends MatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public MatPalette overridePalette(MatPalette palette) {

        palette.setColorPrimary(Color.GRAY);
        palette.setColorPrimaryDark(Color.DKGRAY);
        palette.setColorAccent(Color.LTGRAY);
        return palette;
    }
}
```